# Hooking sys_execve on Linux kernel 4.6 or higher

Tags: c, linux-kernel, hook

Kernels lower than 4.6 use assembly stubs to harden the hooking of critical system calls like fork, clone, exec etc. Particularly speaking for execve, the following snippet from [Kernel-4.5](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.5.7/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S) shows entry stub of execve:

```
ENTRY(stub_execve)
    call    sys_execve
return_from_execve:
 ... 
END(stub_execve)
```

System [call table](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.5.7/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) contains this stub's address and this stub further calls original execve. So, to hook execve in this environment we need to patch `call sys_execve` in stub with our hooking routine and after doing our desired things call the original execve. This all can be seen in action in [execmon](https://github.com/kfiros/execmon), a process execution monitoring utility for linux. I'd tested execmon successfully working in Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.

Starting from kernel 4.6, upper scheme for critical calls protection had been changed. Now the stub looks like:

```
ENTRY(ptregs_\func)
    leaq    \func(%rip), %rax
    jmp     stub_ptregs_64
END(ptregs_\func)
```

where `\func` will expand to `sys_execve` for execve calls. Again, system [call table](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) contains this stub and this stub calls original execve, but now in a more secured manner instead of just doing `call sys_execve`. 
This newer stub, stores called function's address in `RAX` register and jumps to another stub shown below (comments removed):

```
 ENTRY(stub_ptregs_64)
     cmpq   $.Lentry_SYSCALL_64_after_fastpath_call, (%rsp)
     jne    1f

     DISABLE_INTERRUPTS(CLBR_NONE)
     TRACE_IRQS_OFF
     popq   %rax
     jmp    entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path

 1:
     jmp    *%rax        /* called from C */
 END(stub_ptregs_64)
```

Please have a look on [this](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S) to see comments and other referenced labels in this stub.

I'd tried hard to come up with some logic to overcome this protection and patch original calls with hooking functions, but no success yet. 
Would someone like to join me and help to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I completely don't understand where you take the security angle from.

Neither previous nor current from of the func is "hardened".

You never stated why do you want to hook execve either.

The standard hooking mechanism is with kprobes and you can check systemtap for an example consumer.

I had a look at aforementioned 'execmon' code and I find it to be of poor quality and in not fit for learning. For instance https://github.com/kfiros/execmon/blob/master/kmod/syscalls.c#L65

- accesses userspace memory directly (no get_user, copy_from_user etc.)
- does it *twice*. first it computes the lengths (unbound!) and then copies stuff in. in particular if someone made strings longer *after* the compupation, but before they get copied, this triggers a buffer overflow.